# StackLayout vertical centered Items

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Only new to Xamarin forms, I'm using a stackLayout as a row to display three images. I'm trying to get them centered on that row. Maybe the stacklayout isn't the correct approach but i'm not sure what is either. As you can see from the image they are bunched together. I'm looking for them all to be equally spaced out on that row.

[image]

```
var buttonLayout = new StackLayout() 
        { 
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 25, 0, 10),
            Spacing = 10,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
        };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25338534/5064986
http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions/

```
var buttonLayout = new StackLayout() 
        { 
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 25, 0, 10),
            Spacing = 10,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };
```

Comment: Cheers, that sorted it.