# Xamarin Forms view coordinates and Android view coordinates

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, view, coordinates, custom-renderer

PREMISE: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609737/xamarin-forms-ui-coordinate-systemhttps://) does NOT answer my question, here I ask HOW to solve this "conflict problem".

I noticed that coordinates of a view in Xamarin Forms are different from the coordinates of the same view taken in Android, something like `view.X`=150 (in Xamarin Forms) correspond to `view.GetX()`=900 (in Xamarin Android). This causes me a lot of problem, because I am trying to implement drag and drop using android custom renderer, in which I have to know the position of the drop zone (using `myDestinationRect.Contains(myTouchX,myTouchY)`), but since the position that I have in Forms is different from the position needed in the Android custom renderer, that become impossible for me. Is there a way to like "convert" forms coordinates to android coordinates? Or are there any other solutions?

PS: in iOS everything works fine, it seems that Forms and iOS use same coordinates system.

Comment: May be some dpi problem?

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the Device `Density` first,then `*density` to convert to android coordinates.

```
var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
int XForms = view.X;
int XAndroid = XForms*density; //convert to android coordinates.
```