# How to design forms in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, grid

I have Design One page but it not look like the requirement. I am new to Xamarin and I don't know how to design like Attached image.[image]

My Code is

```
 <Grid Margin="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Text="From" Font="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="txtFrom" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ></Entry>
            <Label Text="To" Font="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="txtTo"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Entry>
            <Label Text="Subject" Font="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="txtSubject" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></Entry>
            <Label Text="Body" Font="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"></Label>
            <Editor  x:Name="txtBody" HeightRequest="100"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Editor>
            <Button x:Name="btnSend"  Text="Send" BackgroundColor="Orange" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Button>

        </Grid>
```

My Ui Look like another attached image. [image]

Comment: What's exactly the point you are struggling on? Is it the fonts? The way the components looks like? What do you expect as an answer, the whole xaml code to fit on your design requirements? I couldn't understand well your question

Comment: I want to change components style

Comment: Put place holder on entry, Box view for separation line and Frame for Body

Comment: Have you done this design?

Answer (score 8):

There are three big differences I see between your design and the one you are hoping to replicate:

1. They use `Placeholder`s in their `Entry`s so that when nothing is typed "name" will show up as the `Entry`'s text.
2. The Body `Editor` takes up the entire rest of the available page.
3. The `Editor` for the body is surrounded by a black boarder in the example.

Here is some help to fix each of the issues:

**Issue 1: Using Placeholders**

Instead of using a `Label` next to your `Entry` for each input, you can instead use the `Placeholder` of the `Entry`.  The `Entry` will show the value in `Placeholder` whenever the `Entry` is empty.

For example you could change the name `Entry` to:

```
<Entry x:Name="txtFrom" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="Name" ></Entry>
```

With this implementation, you wouldn't even need the columns for the `Grid` since you don't need the `Label`s

[Here's documentation for `Entry` and the `Placeholder`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry/)

**Issue 2: Filling the Page with your `Editor`**

In order to make your `Editor` take up the remaining room on the page, you need to use the `FillAndExpand` Layout options property. I would personally recommend taking your editor out of the `Grid`, and surrounding it all in a `StackLayout` like this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid>
        <!--Your Grid without the Editor-->
    </Grid>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Editor VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <!--Put your button here-->
</StackLayout>
```

[Here's documentation for Xamarin's `LayoutOptions`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options/)

[Here's a good SO Post about `LayoutOptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338533/what-is-the-difference-between-xamarin-forms-layoutoptions-especially-fill-and)

**Issue 3: Adding a border around your `Editor`**

There isn't really a good way to add a border in Xamarin.Forms.  According to [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/122142/#Comment_122142) putting a `StackLayout` with a different `BackgroundColor` inside another `StackLayout` and adding `Padding` can do this.  I've implemented it here:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="4" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="4">
        <!--Put your editor here-->
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Who not use the Frame Element, it is quite similar to the WPF Border? 

<Frame BorderColor="Black" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
 <!--Put your editor here-->
</Frame>

Answer (score 1):

Use .Xaml file for design forms in xamarin.form.

see Xamarin official  tutorial 
https://developer.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and worked perfectly!

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical"BackgroundColor="Accent" Padding="4">
 <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" Padding="4">
                <ScrollView>
                    <Editor
                        Text="Write Corrections Here..."
                        MaxLength="250"
                        HeightRequest="100"
                        WidthRequest="320"
                        BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" 
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"                        
                        IsSpellCheckEnabled="True">
                    </Editor>
                </ScrollView>
            </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```